# Does a ValueType get boxed when is declared as part of a class?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, boxing, unboxing

Considering this class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Int32 MyField;
}
```

I guess the "MyField" member is not on the thread stack because as it could be accessed by several threads, it has to be definitely in the managed heap, but does it means it is boxed and unboxed everytime it is used?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that many explanations of how value types differ from reference types may mislead the reader, because they tend to say that value types exist on the stack; which is only really the case if you're talking about value type variables declared within a method. I thought James Curran's answer here had a good suggestion of using the terms "Over Here" and "Over There" to describe the location of memory allocated for an object rather than "In the Stack" and "In the Heap": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790436/where-are-value-types-stored-in-c-generic-collections/3790468#3790468

Comment: And even when a value type variable is declared within a method, it can be moved to the heap for any number of reasons.  See Eric Lippert's "The Truth About Value Types."  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not boxed every time it is used.  Boxing only occurs when you are coercing a value type into a reference type - it really has nothing to do with where the actual memory for the value was allocated (or even if any memory was allocated).

In your case, it's how you act on MyField that will determine if it's boxed, not how Foo is treated.

```
  //No Boxing
  var f = new Foo();
  f.MyField = 5;
  int val = f.MyField;


  //Boxing
  var f = new Foo();
  f.MyFIeld = 5;
  object val = f.MyField;
```

Note that in the second example `val` now contains a reference to a boxed int.  `MyField` is still (and will always remain) an unboxed int and can be accessed without unboxing (thanks for pointing out the needed clarification, [LukeH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55847/lukeh))

Comment: Worth emphasising that in your second example the `val` variable is the boxed `int`; `MyField` itself is never boxed.

Answer (score 2):

No, the value type is not boxed.

Boxing only occurs when you use a value type as though it is an object, for example when storing an `int` in an array of `object`.  That is:

```
object[] a = new object[10];
int x = 1;
a[0] = x;
```

In that case, the value type is boxed.

But a value type stored as a field inside a class is not boxed.

Answer (score 2):

No, boxing only occurs when a value type is treated as a System.Object (usually by implicit casting, i.e. passing it as a method parameter)

Answer (score 1):

Value types only get boxed when they're assigned to a reference type variable (e.g. `object`). If you never assign `MyField` to anything other than an int or another struct to which it can be cast (e.g. `double`), it won't ever be boxed.